# Android phone plugged into charge 24/7

Tags: battery, charging

I currently have an LG E440 (non-stock ROM) plugged on charge 24/7 (connected to mains outlet, not PC) as it runs several Tasker-based routines which need to be seperate from my day-to-day phone.

Aside from the shortened battery life-span and increased electricity bill, are there any inherent dangers to this? E.g. battery exploding, risk of fire etc.

As far as I'm aware, as long as the battery doesn't overheat it should be fine, but I'm sure someone out there can point something out!

Thanks

Comment: That should be fine IMO. By doing it via a battery bank you can eliminate risk of freak power surges due to lightning etc. Other than that you have no problems